# Can I change the keyboard backlight?

Tags: dell-inspiron, backlight

I recently bought a Dell Inspiron 15 7559. It has a backlit keyboard, with 3 brightness settings. Is it possible to customize the colors, or can it only be white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That laptop only has white backlight. If you want custom colors, look for a laptop with "RGB backlighting". Note, these laptops are generally gaming laptops.

Comment: You dont have to reject the edits, there is an approval process.  Just ignore it and it will go away.